Why does LaTeXML generated output show directory content instead of HTML page
I am learning LaTeXML. For the first attempt, I have downloaded LaTeXML-master, in its doc/ makemanual file removed commands generating pods and schema, then generated the manual.
(I used ./makemanual, without any arguments)
The .pdf output is fine, and part of the .html is fine too. However, part of the links leads to not the pages I want; instead, the content of its subdirectory is shown.
As I observed (just a guess now) that it works fine if the referred file is in the same subdirectory. That is
<a href="./manual/index.html" The Manual</span></a>

works as expected, but (as the compiler delivers)
<a href="./manual" The Manual</span></a>

shows the subdirectory only. The reference is OK (if I click on the corresponding file, the expected content shows up.)
Do I have a wrong setting, or doing wrong something?
(I am using Ubuntu 22.04)

I'm afraid a lot of information (code) is missing so people here can replicate your situation/problem. Please add to your question, keeping in mind, that nobody can look over your shoulder ,,, Thank you

@MS-SPO On my screen I see the needed two code lines and it looks like, David Carlisle could read it over my shoulder :-o) Thanks for replying.

Fine :) Well ... Davids spirit is known to hover of the waters every now and then ... ;)

See --urlstyle at https://math.nist.gov/~BMiller/LaTeXML/manual/commands/latexmlpost.html
By default latexml assumes you are using a web server that will return index.html on directory requests. You can configure this with --urlstyle=file in which case it produces urls that would work off the filesystem and need the explicit index.html

--urlstyle=(server|negotiated|file)


This option determines the way that URLs within the documents are formatted, depending on the way they are intended to be served. The default, server, eliminates unnecessary trailing index.html. With negotiated, the trailing file extension (typically html or xhtml) are eliminated. The scheme file preserves complete (but relative) urls so that the site can be browsed as files without any server.


Thank you. I am tying to change as little as possible while beginner. This time it was a bad policy.
